# Django Tastypie User Registration

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I am creating an API using Django and TastyPie. I am trying to register a user via a resource. I took most of my code from this question that has a similar goal:

[How to create or register User using django-tastypie API programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889153/how-to-create-or-register-user-using-django-tastypie-api-programmatically)

My problem is, I get a problem when registering a user.

The code is:

```
class RegisterUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        object_class = VouchersUser

        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        include_resource_uri = False
        fields = ['username']

        resource_name = 'register'

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            bundle = super(RegisterUserResource).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
            bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
            bundle.obj.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('User with this username already exists')
        return bundle
```

When I send a POST (I do it programatically) with both username and password parameters, though, I get the following error back:

```
{"error_message": "The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your formats and content_types on your Serializer.", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 195, in wrapper
 response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 402, in dispatch_list
 return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 431, in dispatch
 response = method(request, **kwargs)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 1176, in post_list
 deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line 351, in deserialize
 deserialized = self._meta.serializer.deserialize(data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.7.egg/tastypie/serializers.py", line 192, in deserialize
 raise UnsupportedFormat("The format indicated '%s' had no available deserialization method. Please check your formats and content_types on your Serializer." % format)

UnsupportedFormat: The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your formats and content_types on your Serializer.
"}
```

I can deduce there is some problem with the serializer but which and how can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: I tried this out, and it doesn't fail on submitting the same username again. Actually it creates the user again with the same username. wonder why..

Comment: I see. can you tell me how did you execute the POST request?

Comment: Posted a json with username and password based on http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#creating-a-new-resource-post. ALso I am using django-nonrel with appengine, so that might also be the issue. WIll investigate next week..

Comment: This code doesn't work for me unless I change it to from `super(RegisterUserResource)` to `super(RegisterUserResource, self)`. FYI.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to use `django.test.client.post` with Tastypie. If so, you need to pass in an extra parameter - the content_type. Here is how your call should look:

```
client.post('/resource/to/create/', 'json_string_here', content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this ASAP and answer back.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue. passing "Content-Type: application/json" in header solved it for me.