# How I can create an object in Tastypie API?

Tags: django, api, post, tastypie

I am creating a Tastypie API for my Django project. I have a models in django models.py like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    nick = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 511)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 63)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField('register date')
    od_user = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)

    def __unicode__(self):
        aux = self.nick + " " + self.email
        return aux
```

and I also have a ModelResource for my Tastypie API like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      resource_name = 'user'
      excludes = ['password']
      allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
      authorization = Authorization()
      always_return_data=True

   def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
      username, password = bundle.data['nick'], bundle.data['password']
      try:
          bundle.obj = User(nick, "email@test", password,timezone.now(),"od_test")
          bundle.obj.save()
      except IntegrityError:
          raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
      return bundle
```

but this doesn't work. I've looked [How to create or register User using django-tastypie API programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889153/how-to-create-or-register-user-using-django-tastypie-api-programmatically) but I don't know how create a user in my database.

I use:

```
   curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"nick":"test2", "password":"alparch"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json
```

to do POST method.

How can I create an object with a Tastypie API?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens when you post? Is there an error?

Comment: The error is :"error_message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test2' test2 is the nick name that I post

Comment: You should consider using the `User` model included in `django.contrib.auth`. By writing your own, you lose some functionality -- for example you are storing an unencrypted password, which is not secure.

Comment: I know but I want to do it manually. This it's only a test. Then I save a resume to password with a SHA-512 algorithm. Thanks for the comment!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a user with positional arguments in the way you have:

```
User(nick, "email@test", password,timezone.now(),"od_test")
```

Instead, you must use keyword arguments:

```
User(nick=nick,
     email="email@test",
     ...
     )
```