# Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am creating a mobile app where I need to use authentication. How can I achieve the following:

1. I need to create a user.  After creating the user it needs to send `Api_client` and a secret as a response to the user.
2. I have a function to perform verification.  After creating the user it needs to call the function for mobile verification.
3. Importantly, how can I stop a user who uses a for loop and starts adding users?

I tried this:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
```

That created an API key but is not sending it as a response when creating the user is successful.

Answer (score 2):

*Here's what I understand from your question :*

1. You want any user of your mobile app to register himself,
   anonymously, as a user to your Django application.
2. This request must trigger a Tastypie api_key creation, and then return it.
3. You want to prevent this request from being spammed.

*I don't understand this :*

"I have a function for mobile without verification. After creating the user it needs to call the function for mobile verification."

---

To answer the points I get :

1. **See this SO question regarding user registration with Tastypie** [How to create or register User using django-tastypie API programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889153/how-to-create-or-register-user-using-django-tastypie-api-programmatically), notably this part :

   ```
   def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
       username, password = bundle.data['username'], bundle.data['password']
       try:
           bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username, '', password)
       except IntegrityError:
           raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
       return bundle
   ```

   **For a complete walkthrough, check this article** : http://psjinx.com/programming/2013/06/07/so-you-want-to-create-users-using-djangotastypie/
2. You're on the right track regarding the api_key creation, except **you have to tell the api to actually      send it back**. You can use the regular way (it requires another request, though) :

   i.e make it accessible from UserResource, as described in the article linked above, specifically :

   ```
   def dehydrate(self, bundle):
       bundle.data['key'] = bundle.obj.api_key.key

       try:
           # Don't return `raw_password` in response.
           del bundle.data["raw_password"]
       except KeyError:
           pass

       return bundle
   ```

   If you want to send it right after a User's registration, don't forget to set "always_return_data" to True and **add the api_key to the response**.
3. Spam / loop registration :

   You should look into your **server's capabilities regarding this matter**. For example, assuming you're using Nginx : http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule

   Another option might be to use this : http://django-ratelimit-backend.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Hope this helps !

Regards,

Comment: after many days of waiting . u guided me to sucess. thank youmuch :) very

Comment: If it's related to the original question, feel free I'll update if I can answer. Otherwise you might be better off opening another thread :)